# Parse Trees and Operator Precedence

Tags: formal-grammars

I have the following basic BNF grammar:

```
<A>   -->  <id>  = <E>
<id>  -->  A | B | C | D | F
<E> --> <E> + <T> | <T>
<T> --> <T> * <F> | <F>
<F> --> <E> | <id>
```

Operator (*) should have higher precedence over (+).
However, see this statement:

```
A = A + B + C + D * F
```

The leftmost derivation (and parse tree) indicate the opposite! i.e., (+) has higher precedence than (*) since it will show up lower in the parse tree!

What am I missing here?

Comment: Normally the last production would be `<F> --> ( <E> ) | <id>` in order to allow parenthesised expressions. As written, your grammar is highly ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the path

```
<E>  ->  <T>  ->  <F>  ->  <id>,
```

you can completely circumvent the "check" for whether there are `*`.

Think about it in a bottom up manner: only if there's no `*` nearby can you parse a `+`.